# Java loading a DLL that export methods from another DLL in JNI

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface

i did a DLL that export methods from another DLL in JNI.

```
    JNIEXPORT bool JNICALL getIsWordInPhonemListFR(const char* word)
{
    isWordInPhonemListFR method = NULL;
    BOOL fRunTimeLinkSuccess = FALSE;

    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(L"PhoneticEngineFR2.dll");
    if (!hGetProcIDDLL) {

        std::cout << "kcould not load the dynamic library" << std::endl;

    }else{
        method = (isWordInPhonemListFR)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "isWordInPhonemListFR");
    }

    return method(word);
}
```

System.load in java doesn't give any errors but when i want to use my native method, i get a

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

Both DLLs are in the same folder in my project. It was working fine when working in visual studio but there is something wrong with the export in JNI. The JNI onLoad also doesn't trigger in java.

Thanks

Comment: It's working, see answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am dumb, i had a Namespace over all my JNI export methods.
Therefore, they were not executed. Now it works.